# Center subviews horizontally with auto layout

Tags: iphone, objective-c, alignment, autolayout

I have two subviews, an `UILabel` and an `UIImageView`, which I would like to center in a view. They should be placed next to each other and together they should be in the center of their superview whose width is known.

I would also like to be able to add some spacing between the views.

Is this possible with auto layout?

```
-------------------------------
|           Superview         |
|                             |
|     [label] [imageview]     |
-------------------------------
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

wrap the label & imageview in a wrapview

then autoresize the wrapview using

```
view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
```

[image]

Comment: This way, I will have to manually change the size of the wrapview when the width of the label changes, right?

Comment: yes, if the label is not fixed, or there's no way to autolayout :)